# Area of the union of rectangles anchored on the x-axis

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am trying to solve the following computational geometry problem.

> Let $S$ be a set of $n$ axis-parallel rectangles in the plane, so that the bottom edge of each rectangle in $S$ lies on the $x$-axis.
>
> 1. What is (an upper bound on) the combinatorial complexity of the union $K$ of the rectangles in $S$?
> 2. Give an efficient algorithm for computing the union and its area.

I suggest using sweep line algorithm for the purpose of computing union of areas.
First we should consider queue of events. Events are just the leftmost and the rightmost $x$'s of rectangle. As in standard interpretation all $x$'s should be sorted.

Start iterations on event queue (like in standard algorithm). On every new event we can compute an area we've already covered. When two or more rectangles intersect (can be identified by data structure) we should pick the rectangle with the biggest $y$-coordinate until the next event.

That's a general idea. The main difference from the classic sweep line algorithm is that we don't have to compute intersection and inserting them to queue.  All we are interested in is intersection of rectangles which occur on vertical lines of leftmost $x$ and rightmost $x$.

I am not completely sure that the solution I presented is the correct one. This exercice was marked with high complexity grade. Maybe I missed something?

In addition, I don't know how to answer the first question.

Comment: What is the complexity of your approach? I can think of an $O(n\log n)$ solution.

Comment: The complexity of sweep line algorithm is $O((n+l)logn)$, where $l$ - number of intersections.Because we don't consider intersection, the complexity I assume is $O(nlogn)$

Comment: Your solution is not really optimal. The number of intersections could be $\Omega(n^2)$ in the worst case. As Syzgy points out, a better solution can be constructed. Hint: think divide and conquer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the "combinatorial complexity of the union"? Do you mean the complexity of *computing* the union? I am not familiar with the notion of complexity of a region.

Comment: Neither do I. I'll ask my teacher later. In your opinion does the ideal look good?

Comment: Your approach should work, if I understood it correctly. Since the only event points are left and right boundary points of rectangles, the number of event points stays in $O(n)$. Intersection points are never computed or considered. Preprocessing takes $O(n\log n)$, and processing an event point costs constant.

Comment: The standard definition of combinatorial complexity of the union is the number of vertices in the boundary, i.e., the number of places where the boundary takes a "turn". Your approach will perform badly for the following example: rectangle 1 starts at x coordinate 0 and ends at x coordinate n and has a height 1, rectangle 2 starts at x coordinate 1 and ends at x coordinate n-1 and has height 2, rectangle 3 starts at 2 and ends at n-2 with height 3 and so on.

Comment: So, btw, the combinatorial complexity of the union can be at most O(n) because each rectangle can contribute to only a constant number of turns on the boundary.

Comment: @VinayakPathak, thank you very much for the comments. You described exactly the worst case scenario and it's time complexity is $O(nlogn)$. Thanks for the definition of combinatorial complexity

Comment: I don't think it will be $O(n\log n)$. When your sweeping algorithm is right in the middle in the bad example that I mentioned, you will have n things stored in the queue. But an adversary can make the right edges of these n rectangles occur in any order. Since whenever you find a right edge, you need to decide which rectangle to remove from your queue, each of these events might take linear time to process. Linear number of events with linear processing time for each is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: and in the case when status data structure is tree, O(nlogn)?

Comment: @com: There isn't just one "sweepline algorithm".  What information do you need to maintain about the intersection of the sweepline and the rectangles?  (Hint: It's **not** the complete sorted list of intersection points.)  What data structure efficiently maintains that information as things are inserted and deleted?  (Hint: It's **not** a "queue" or a "tree".)  Also, Vinayak's comment is incorrect — When the sweepline reaches the right edge of rectangle $i$, you must delete rectangle $i$ from the data structure.  There is nothing to decide.

Comment: @JeffE, I assume we don't need intersection points at all, only $y$ coordinate of intersection points. And I really don't have an idea where to store them if not in tree.

Comment: Think about **what** you want the data structure to do, not the implementation details of **how** it should do it.  Abstract data type, not concrete data structure.  And no, you don't need the $y$ coordinates of all the intersection points, just some of them.  But which ones?

Comment: @JeffE, I like your comments. It looks like I need all $y$'s that lower than the current $y$, all there $y$'s I insert to status data structure. From data structure I need to pull the maximum $y$ from all y's in status, so sorted list should be sufficient.

Comment: The bottom edge of the rectangles on the x axis is a nice simplification. This looks a lot like a skyline...

Comment: @com, do you want to answer your own question?